# Xcode Custom Manifest Plist On Enterprise Ad Hoc Distribution

Tags: ios, xcode, plist

I use Xcode's Enterprise Ad Hoc Distribution to deliver my beta app to testers and I need to include in the generated plist file the build number (CFBundleVersion) under the "Metadata" dictionary.

How can I make Xcode to automatically add CFBundleVersion to the plist file when creating the distribution?

Answer (score 0):

Try to read this: http://www.alauda.ro/2013/10/11/how-to-add-incremental-build-numbering-in-xcode-5/

Hope, it can help you

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't do what I need. It only increments the build number in bundle's .plist file.